# Jackson Mapper on Spring Boot. Inheritance and order of elements on serialization

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, objectmapper

I'm trying to set up the order of the serializated attributes on inheritance.

I have a @MappedSuperClass, BaseEntity, with Id, creationDate, modificationDate, creationUser, modificationUser.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
@GenericGenerator(name = "db-uuid", strategy = "guid")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "db-uuid")
protected String id;

@NotNull
@PastOrPresent
@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
protected Date creationDate;
@PastOrPresent
protected Date modificationDate;

protected String creationUser;
protected String modificationUser;
```

And every Entity extends from this one. For example

```
@Entity(name = "Technician")
public class AsnTechnician extends BaseEntity {
    private String name;
    private String sex;
}
```

When jackson is serializing this object, the order is : `{id, creationDate, modificationDate, creationUser, modificationUser, name, sex}`. And I would like something like: `{id, name, sex, creationDate, modificationDate, creationUser, modificationUser}`

The point here is, using inheritance, I don't know how to properly manage the order of attributes. Is there a way of doing so without having to declare it in every single Entity extending BaseEntity?

I know it's not important, it's just for the sake of readability! Also, I know I should be using DTOs for the output of the controller and not the Entities, that will come later.

I've tried with `@JsonProperty(index=1)` under id and works like a charm. But I don't know how to tell Jackson that the others should go the last ones. Tried with `@JsonProperty(index=99)` and so, but does not work, they go after `id` and before `AsnTechnician` attributes

Is there a way to tell jackson that there are some properties (of the parent class) that I want to be first (id) and last (creationDate)?

Answer (score 0):

Use @JsonPropertyOrder for ordering the Json elements. Also, make sure both BaseEntity and the Entity has Getter and Setter.

```
@Entity(name = "Technician")
@JsonPropertyOrder({"id", "name", "sex", "creationDate", "modificationDate", "creationUser", "modificationUser"}
public class AsnTechnician extends BaseEntity {
    private String name;
    private String sex;
}
```